# How do I retrieve the information thats in the chrome "Source" tab with python?

Tags: python

For example when you go into chrome and open a website, then go to the devtools and open up the sources tab, how would i get basically everything that is in there myself with python? Like download it with python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few popular ways to interact with web content in Python, like controlling the browser with automation, for example with `selenium`. This will allow you to click and extract elements from a webpage. See [this example](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html).

An alternative would be to use a library like `beautifulsoup` to request the webpage and parse it within your Python script. This is usually the preferred method if you don't want the dependency of an actual browser (like in headless environments). More info in [the official docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).